# Do intuitionists and predicativists have an overly "absolute" concept of infinity?

Tags: philosophy-of-mathematics, infinity, relativism

Sifting through the historical data, I get the impression that intuitionism is not strictly a case of finitism (much less ultrafinitism), but more like ["parafinitism"](https://www.maa.org/press/maa-reviews/the-long-shadow-of-the-parafinite-three-scenes-from-the-prehistory-of-a-concept). Predicativism, in turn, seemingly tends to involve accepting countable infinity as actualized/complete, with uncountable infinity being the incompletable realm of judgment. (For example, one predicativist theory is that there are acceptable levels of countable ordinal infinity up through a special such ordinal, [Γ<sub>0</sub>](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/proof-theory/#InfiProoForPredTheo), in some pertinent sense of "acceptable.")

However, I noticed that the predicativist picture of the Continuum, for example, seems directly consonant with forming a version of higher set theory where the powerset function inflates its bases to proper-class size. (See [this dissertation on predicativism](https://www.repository.cam.ac.uk/bitstream/handle/1810/226320/thesis-revised.pdf?sequence=1&isAllowed=y), e.g. pg. 30, for a similar claim about the attempt to form a set of *all* countable ordinals in the first place.) So in a sense, I do not see the "point" of predicativism. The higher set theorists were hardly reluctant, as a rule, to claim that absolute infinity is "unknowable" (this is the singular axiom from which the method of reflection arguments derives its justification). Likewise, in his essay on *V = L* as a restrictive-then-nonrestrictive back-and-forth process of principled distinctions in the ascent of both any given universe and the vertical multiverse moreover, Hamkins portrays the transfinal horizon of that multiverse in a knowledge-restraining form.

As for intuitionists, well, at least if we try to make use of Brouwer's neo-Kantian "freely creating subject," we seem to venture into the realm of neo-Kantian free will, which involves categorical, hence absolute, preconditions. It would be easy to adapt Kant's overview of scientific history (the dialectic between those who try to diversify species and those who try to unify all genera) to set-theoretic history, saying that because of the inaccessibility of the unrestricted transet, the "synthesis" of our representation of *all* levels of relative infinity is not to be completed in a finite time.

If one of the lessons of relativism and postmodernism is that it is harder to prove an absolute than even analytical skeptics might've often supposed, do intuitionists and predicativists not heed that lesson? Even though the predicativist has zillions of countable ordinals, it has only one "real" transfinite cardinal, the zeroth aleph (in principle). The parafinitely paracomplete (epistemically implective) objects of intuitionism's "creating subject" constitute a thematic zone of their own, so to say, but then still all infinitary cardinality is collapsed into one concept (though this concept is virtually never to be positively applied, they will of course say), and so too is ordinal infinity. So either way, these schools of philosophy of mathematics have the fewest distinctions in *metafinite* levels possible (short of ultrafinitism *per se nota*), about one or two, depending on how you parse the question: {finitude}, which itself is not clearly differentiated into {absolute} and {relative} forms, and then also just {infinity}, not {relative infinity} and {absolute infinity} both, except that in predicativism that *is* the **only** listing for the levels (that there are those two).

Comment: Intuitionism is strictly *not* finitism because the Kantian subject has open-ended synthetic ability. Predicativism, on the other hand, *is* motivated by finitism. We cannot count on actual infinity existing and taking care of consistency for us when we venture into infinity *talk*. Hence we need to regiment its fictions in a way that precludes inconsistency with our own hands. Definitions do not pick out pre-existing platonic objects, they systematically introduce empty labels. Predicativity is the hygiene of blocking self-referential "labels" with shifting referents as in the Berry paradox.

Comment: @Conifold isn't intuitionism parafinitistic? But predicativism has, historically, survived mainly in a form that is amenable to particular, hence actual, layers of countable infinity, but not to a sum over all possible such infinity (this is the contention of much of the dissertation linked in the OP).

Comment: Intuitionism conceptualizes infinity as potential, but goes far beyond the finite with it, including continuum. Predicativism, on the other hand, does not tie math to metaphysics of the infinite closely. It is more a methodological position, motivated by finitism, but compatible, in principle, with any metaphysics. So, perhaps paradoxically, it is amenable to *talk* (or intensional conceptualization) of much more than finitist or even intuitionist strictures allow, as long as the talk is *assuredly consistent*. "Actual" infinity is a figure of speech, or intension, see ch.6 of your link.